# SSIS Package in VS2015

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2015

What do I need to develop SSIS ETL packages in Visual Studio 2015. I have installed [SSDT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx). I am still not able to see Integration Services project in new project menu in Visual studio 2015.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as SSDT installed properly, it should be under `File -> New -> Project...`

Then you should see this:
[image]

Look under `Templates -> Business Intelligence -> Integration Services`. There you will find the SSIS project templates.